# Difference between material and print-material tags

Tags: discussion, tags

There must be a subtle difference, that I can't quite see, between [material](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/material) and [print-material](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/print-material).

The print-material tag clearly states that it is different from material:

> Print-material, in comparison to the tag 'material', helps to specify that the question is concerned with the material the print itself is made from. This includes 'filament' as a subgroup but also SLS polymers for example.

Where as [material](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/material) states, more or less, the same thing:

> For questions about compatible 3D printing materials.
>
> For questions regarding 3D printable materials such as whether a material is capable of being 3D printed, optimal 3D printing parameters (ie. extrusion temp), mechanical properties of materials, etc.

To me, even though [print-material](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/print-material) states that it differs from [material](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/material), I can't really see the difference, *unless* material is a superset of print-material, and not only confined to being printed, but also construction of a printer (i.e. acrylic, wood, steel, aluminium, etc.). If the latter, then the description of [material](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/material) is a bit misleading and may require expansion.

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree, there's not much difference inherently between these two tags. However, we could try to direct the use of [material](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/material) to more general (not necessarily 3D printed material) vs the obviously focused [print-material](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/print-material).

Or we could just merge them into the [print-material](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/print-material) tag (my vote).

Comment: I might not merge them, as there is one (or two), out of 33, that aren't filament related, i.e. [How to reuse modelling bases for the Stratasys uPrint SE Plus?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/1471/how-to-reuse-modelling-bases-for-the-stratasys-uprint-se-plus)